# Can access docker registry locally but not using the server IP - need help to troubleshoot

Tags: docker

I can able to access the Docker registry(Public regitry) locally, but when trying to access with server IP - It throws either certificate error or just a blank page.
Im using Docker version - 18.9. 
Please let me know any help on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGR2N.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. When you use HTTPS, the protocol checks that the server has a certificate for the name that you called it with. The Docker registry has a certificate which is valid for "gcr.io", not for any IP you can use to reach it (and this IP is probably not the same for everybody...). If you cannot resolve the name using a DNS, you can add the Name/IP pair in your `/etc/hosts` so you can still use the name in HTTPS requests.